# Customize beamer template to vary field for each slide?

Tags: beamer

I would like to use the lower left corner normally reserved for "author (institution)" (I am using the Boadilla template) to include additional text (like references/sources for figures) specific to that slide. Is this easy to customize? If so... how can I go about changing that for individual slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example I defined a `\MyText` command which simply redefines de `footline` template by putting the argument in the field reserved for short author and institution. You have to use the command *before* the `\begin{frame}` command and use some grouping mechanism (`\begingroup`, `\endgroup`, for example) to keep the change local:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\author{The author}
\institute{The Institute}
\title{The date}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyInfo[1]{%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}#1
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\MyInfo{Some text}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame with modified footline}
Test frame
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame with standard footline}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\MyInfo{Some other text}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another frame with modified footline}
Test frame
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!!! Works perfectly. This is fantastic. And new macros to digest...

Comment: @crippledlambda: You're welcome. I forgot to mention; the original definition of the `footline` beamer template used by the `infolines` outer theme (which is the outer theme used by `Boadilla`) can be found in the file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`.

Comment: Thanks! So `footline` is called by `beamerouterthemeinfolines`... I was looking at `beamerthemeBoadilla.sty` and was disappointed to see the original not defined there so this is good to know. Using this, I was also able to include `\insertsectionhead` in place of the `\insertshorttitle` which is also a useful modification...