# Customize latex beamer template Boadilla to make the date/slide section display something else

Tags: beamer

My question is very similar to the one asked in

[Customize beamer template to vary field for each slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33160/customize-beamer-template-to-vary-field-for-each-slide/287192#287192)

I would like to use the lower RIGHT corner normally reserved for "Date/slide number" (I am using the Boadilla template) for sections (like introduction, data, results, ...) specific to that slide. Is this easy to customize? If so... how can I go about changing that for individual slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redefine the footline beamer template and define a new beamer template for the bottom right corner. Then you can easily change the content of the bottom right corner with `\setbeamertemplate{right corner}{•}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamertemplate{right corner}{%
\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}%
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber%
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{right corner}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1 - Default}
    Frame Content
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{right corner}{\insertshortdate{}}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2 - Date only}
    Frame Content
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3 - Default}
    Frame Content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to change the right corner normally reserved for "Date/slide number" such that it's different for different slide. It seems like this solution would only work if I want the same for all slide. Say I have 3 slides. For the first slide I just want the right corner to say the date, for the second slide I want it to say "Introduction", and for the third slide I want it to say "results". How should I do this?

Comment: I updated my example to make it easier to change the bottom right corner for every frame individually.